# Can we use different form pattern based on the context in a single app?

Tags: forms, user-centered-design

I am using a right aligned label form for web app (considering the long nature of the form avoided top aligned label). However can I switch to top aligned label if my form is short e.g Signin/up page? Do I have to maintain the same styling for the mobile app as well? As I can clearly see, the right aligned label will be a very bad choice for the mobile. [image]

Answer (score 2):

The better solution is maintaining one concept throughout the application (this includes code scaling)

However, in critical cases styling can be changed - this requires a separate css code.

I wonder, however, in an aesthetic context, is the alignment to the right justified?

And whether just just left or above input would not be a better solution

[image]

Why?

Consider eye fixation

[image]

Comment: I did my research on this. Clearly top aligned labels provides better scannability but not ideal for long form plus if we have more horizontal space. I would also like to mention the fixation in both the cases will come to closest once user starts typing and move to next field . By right aligned level I meant the label which are right aligned and stay closest to the input field. Right or left aligned label always  takes less vertical space in comparison to top aligned label.

Comment: Also right aligned label is not bad choice. Yes scalability definitely is compromised in comparison to top aligned label, but not the worst  one. This pattern encourages spot pattern plus the label always stays close to center of gaze always. I do agree this is bad if our form is short.